# Json object display in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ionic-framework

Hey guys I am new with this json syntax and I have one problem.
I made function that gets data from remote server in json like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function getStates(value) {

            var data = {
                q: value
            } 

            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://something.hr/api/search',
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'},
                data: data
            }).done(function(data) {
                //do something with data I returned to you
                console.log("success")
                console.log(data)


            }).fail(function(data) {
                //doSomethingWith the data I returned to you
                console.log("fail")
                console.log(data)
            });
        };



  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" onkeyup="getStates(this.value)" >
    <br>

 <script>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that I know how to get object in console log, but i wish to get that object in html, like in some box, than click on it and open his data(name, id, adress etc.)

Comment: JSON.stringify(data,null,4) will return your json to in a nice string with offset 4. then you can insert it in element of your choice.

Comment: Can you provide sample of your JSON ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pfbd8ke6/ this is my result in console log, first i get object, when i open it i get there inromations. So now i wish to have that iformatios sorted in a nice way

Comment: SON.stringify(data,null,4) was a good idea. i used it. Now i got diferent problem. list doesen't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var httpManager = (function() {
  var getData = function(value) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.github.com/users/zixxtrth',
      method: 'GET'

    }).done(function(data) {
      //do something with data I returned to you
      jQuery('#avatar').attr('src', data.avatar_url);
      jQuery('#name').html(data.name);
      jQuery('#username').html(data.login);

    }).fail(function(data) {
      //doSomethingWith the data I returned to you
      alert('No Data');
    });
  };

  return {
    getData: getData()
  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='' id='avatar' width='200' height='200' />
<h1 id='name'></h1>
<h2 id='username'></h2>
```